# HTML Form causing second vertical scroll bar until form is in viewport

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm having an issue with a form in my HTML footer, it seems to be causing a second scroll bar on the vertical axis, does anyone have any suggestions on how to eliminate this second scroll bar issue?

I've tried a few different rearrangements, it seems once I comment out the form that it fixes my issue perfectly, so I've definitely isolated the problem to the form itself, what am I missing?

codepen: https://codepen.io/roomwillow/pen/WNoVoOq

HTML:

```
<div class="top"></div>

<footer> 
    <div id="footerFlexContainer">
        <div id="leftFooterFlex">
        <img id="footerLogo" src="content/logos/dig-500x-white.png" alt="Logo">
        <div id="menu3" class="footerMenus">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Sitemap</a> </li>
                <li class="menu3div">
                    <p>|</p>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Legal</a> </li>
                <li class="menu3div">
                  <p>|</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>Copyright 2021</p>
                </li>
                <li class="menu3div">
                  <p>|</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>Company Ltd.</p>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightFooterFlex">
        <ul id="menu4" class="footerMenus">
            <li><a href="https://speed.cloudflare.com/">Speed Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Project Send</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p id="newsletterTitle">Subscribe To Our Newsletter:</p>
        <form id="newsletterForm">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>     
        <ul id="socialGrey" class="social">
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovGrey" src="content/images/footer/facebookHover.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovGrey" src="content/images/footer/instagramHover.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovGrey" src="content/images/footer/linkedinHover.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovGrey" src="content/images/footer/twitterHover.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovGrey youtube" src="content/images/footer/youtubeHover.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="socialWhite" class="social">
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovWhite" src="content/images/footer/facebook.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovWhite" src="content/images/footer/instagram.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovWhite" src="content/images/footer/linkedin.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovWhite" src="content/images/footer/twitter.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="hovWhite youtube" src="content/images/footer/youtube.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*Text*/
h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22pt;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.08rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
  color: white;
}

.top {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 1900px;
}

/* Black on White */
.button1 {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid white 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

/* White on Black */
.button2 {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid black 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.button2:hover {
  background-color: black;
    color: white;
}




/* CSS Document */ /* Footer */
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#footerFlexContainer {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#leftFooterFlex {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
}
#rightFooterFlex {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    align-items: end;
    justify-items: end;
}
.footerMenus a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.08rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.footerMenus a:hover{
    color: lightgrey;
}
#menu3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
#menu3 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
#menu4 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
#menu4 li {
    margin-bottom: 1.15rem;
}
#newsletterTitle {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    align-self: start;
    
}
#newsletterForm {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
#rightFooterFlex input[type=text] {
    padding: 0.25rem;
    width: 10rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    outline: none;
} /*Form Input Field*/
#rightFooterFlex input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
    padding: 0.35rem 0.7rem;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
} /*Form Submit Button (Non Hover)*/
#rightFooterFlex input[type=button], input[type=submit]:hover {
    padding: 0.35rem 0.7rem;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
} /*Form Submit Button (Hover)*/
.social {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}
.social li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
#socialWhite li:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.social img {
    height: 2.25rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 865px) {
    #footerFlexContainer {
        height: 18rem;
    }
    #leftFooterFlex {
        grid-template-rows: 75% 25%;
        margin-left: 2.25rem;
    }
    #menu3 {
        align-self: end;
    }
    #footerLogo {
        height: 10rem;
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
        align-self: end;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }
    #rightFooterFlex {
        margin-right: 2.25rem;
        text-align: right;
        grid-tempate-rows: 2fr 3.5rem 1fr;
    }
    .social li {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 865px) {
    #footerFlexContainer {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    }
    #leftFooterFlex {
        order: 2;
        grid-template-rows: 100%;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        height: auto;
    }
    #menu3 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
        align-self: end;
    }
    #rightFooterFlex {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        justify-items: start;
        height: 14.5rem;
        grid-template-rows: auto 3.5rem 4.25rem;
    }
    #footerLogo {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu3 {
        align-self: center;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    #menu3 li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1.15rem;
    }
    .menu3div {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in Firefox v86, fixed by updating to v86.0.1

Answer (score 0):

your answer in short: Use display and overflow properties

For the long answer, visit these websites:

[CSS overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

[CSS Display property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm aware of display types and overflows, however, you can see by inspecting element, that there's nothing obviously overflowing its bounds, I'm having a hard time identifying which part exactly of the form is causing the issue, and leading it to overflow.